# Word Replacement won't replace deceased on contact profile

Tags: contacts, word-replacements

We are using the deceased function for both contacts that are deceased or no longer employed. In word replacements we changed "Deceased" to "Terminated or Deceased" - however, on the contact profile page (deceased) still appears, so we added a word replacement that makes "(deceased)" replaced by "(Terminated or Deceased)" but that still didn't change it. I was able to replicate on the D7 Demo Master.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's case-sensitive, so if you want to do exact match you can make two entries in word replacements:

- deceased => Terminated or Deceased
- Deceased => Terminated or Deceased

(without the brackets)